# UICollectionView Assertion failure in deleteItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uicollectionview

Here is my error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[PSUICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionView.m:2801
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
[self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]]];
```

Why is this happening, any ideas?

Comment: You get any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Do you remove the item from your model as well? So, for example, if the number of rows, sections and the content they present is taken from a dictionary of arrays whose keys represent the sections and each array the rows, then if you delete one row with `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` you're responsible to update the dictionary accordingly. `UICollectionView` will not do it for you.

Comment: In my case, *not updating* the model *before* the `deleteItemAtIndexPath` was the *reason for the error*

Comment: this worked for me. should be marked as the solution

Answer (score 5):

Note that you are trying to delete index 1 from section 1. Both index and section starts at 0.

i did it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *forms; // datasource item data for all the cells
int indexToDelete; // Set to the index you want to delete

...

[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^(void){
    [forms removeObjectAtIndex:indexToDelete]; // First delete the item from you model
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToDelete inSection:0]]];
            } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that your collection view is not busy with something else when you call deleteItemsAtIndexPaths: .
I experienced the same problem with insertItemsAtIndexPaths: method, and it turned out that it was caused by a bug in my code - I called [myCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:] immediately after calling [my collectionView reloadData] . So, at the moment of calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths: my collection view was reloading its data. After I fixed this bug, the problem with assertion failure has gone.